# Ubuntu Swap on EC2 with an EBS root

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, swap

Running Ubuntu 11.04(natty) on an EC2 micro instance. Setup 1gb swap file at /mnt/swap. Works fine until I reboot and then the swap is not active. I can activate it manually using swapon -a, but my line in /etc/fstab is ignored.

```
/mnt/swap      none    swap    defaults        0       0
```

(I also tried "sw" instead of defaults)

I'm using an EBS backed AMI.

This does work if I put the swap file in other places, but not at /mnt/. I'm curious as to why?

Comment: Minor note: there is no "Ubuntu 11".  There is a released "Ubuntu 11.04" and there will be an "Ubuntu 11.10".  The version number is a combination of the year.month of the release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On instance types other than micro, one of the instance store block devices gets mounted to /mnt. In my micro instance launch, I have a line in fstab for /dev/sdb. I would try removing this line.

Comment: This is your answer.  You need to comment out the pre-existing /mnt line in the /etc/fstab file.